# How can I get the Bot to list/get the participants or members on a group conversation?

Tags: botframework

I have created a skypeBot that can be added to a group conversation.  Is there a way on how the bot can get the list of participants on from the conversation?

Comment: related to https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2992

Comment: Also are you using .net or node?

Comment: @JasonSowers the link provided has only a response for MS Teams.

Comment: One more detail: did you talk about Skype or Skype for Business channel?

Comment: @JasonSowers I'm using .net for the development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways to get the participants of a group conversation with a bot in Skype, but you will get their IDs only:

**Case 1:** By checking the `ConversationUpdate` message that is raised when creating the conversation.

Sample (made with one of my bots):

```
{
    "type": "conversationUpdate",
    "id": "f:6c9b7aa2",
    "timestamp": "2017-06-30T11:40:09.3Z",
    "localTimestamp": null,
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/",
    "channelId": "skype",
    "from": {
        "id": "29:1AE5BB....",
        "name": null
    },
    "conversation": {
        "isGroup": true,
        "id": "19:fd3d....@thread.skype",
        "name": null
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "28:myBotAppId",
        "name": "myBotName"
    },
    "textFormat": null,
    "attachmentLayout": null,
    "membersAdded": [{
        "id": "29:1AE5BB...",
        "name": null
    }, {
        "id": "29:1DwlGVz...",
        "name": null
    }, {
        "id": "28:myBotAppId",
        "name": null
    }],
    "membersRemoved": [],
    "topicName": null,
    "historyDisclosed": null,
    "locale": null,
    "text": null,
    "speak": null,
    "inputHint": null,
    "summary": null,
    "suggestedActions": null,
    "attachments": [],
    "entities": [],
    "channelData": null,
    "action": null,
    "replyToId": null,
    "value": null,
    "name": null,
    "relatesTo": null,
    "code": null
}
```

Here you have 2 users that are in the group conversation in the `membersAdded` block: `29:1AE5BB....` and `29:1DwlGVz...`. The last ID is the bot ID

**Case 2:** by requesting the API.
You can do a GET request to `https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/yourConversationId/members` and you will get the same 2 IDs.

See also more details here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-GetConversationMembers

So from C# code you can do the following:

```
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
var members = connector.Conversations.GetConversationMembersWithHttpMessagesAsync(activity.Conversation.Id).Result.Body;
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the information of the user by these IDs?  so I can get their Firstname and Lastname if  available.

Answer (score 1):

For c# you can try this in the messageController

`ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
            var members = connector.Conversations.GetConversationMembersWithHttpMessagesAsync(activity.Conversation.Id).Result.Body;`

Comment: You're right Jason this method is the encapsulation of my Case2, I had add it in the case!